# camel sftp consumer becomes inactive

Tags: apache, apache-camel, sftp

I am using apache camel version **2.10.0**

I am using **disconnect=true** in my SFTP consumer. This works absolutely fine. However sometimes the consumer becomes completely idle. Upon redeploying the consumer it starts polling again. I have set polling interval as 10 seconds. Here is my complete route configuration.
**Route/ Endpoint**

```
<ftp:binding.sftp xmlns:ftp="urn:switchyard-component-camel-ftp:config:1.1" name="i014-SFTP-Central-abcbank-Local">
<ftp:contextMapper class="com.hm.goep.esb.composer.SI_InContextMapper"/>
<ftp:additionalUriParameters>
    <ftp:parameter name="recursive" value="${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_recursive}"/>
    <ftp:parameter name="antInclude" value="*.csv"/>
    <ftp:parameter name="consumer.bridgeErrorHandler" value="true"/>
    <ftp:parameter name="localWorkDirectory" value="${goep.hm.esb-sap.in.filedirectory}/i014/"/>
    <ftp:parameter name="passiveMode" value="${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_passive_mode}"/>
    <ftp:parameter name="binary" value="true"/>
</ftp:additionalUriParameters>
<ftp:directory>${goep.hm.i014.abcbank.ftpdirectory}</ftp:directory>
<ftp:autoCreate>false</ftp:autoCreate>
<ftp:host>${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_server}</ftp:host>
<ftp:port>${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_port}</ftp:port>
<ftp:username>${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_user}</ftp:username>
<ftp:password>${goep.hm.abcbank.ftp_password}</ftp:password>
<ftp:binary>true</ftp:binary>
<ftp:disconnect>true</ftp:disconnect>
<ftp:stepwise>false</ftp:stepwise>
<ftp:throwExceptionOnConnectFailed>true</ftp:throwExceptionOnConnectFailed>
<ftp:consume>
    <ftp:delete>true</ftp:delete>
    <ftp:sortBy>file:modified</ftp:sortBy>
    <ftp:readLock>changed</ftp:readLock>
    <ftp:startingDirectoryMustExist>true</ftp:startingDirectoryMustExist>
    <ftp:directoryMustExist>true</ftp:directoryMustExist>
    <ftp:delay>${goep.hm.i014.abcbank.inbound.poll_interval}</ftp:delay>
</ftp:consume>
```

**Thread dump**

```
"Connect thread 110.75.144.86 session" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f7450012000 nid=0x1800 runnable [0x00007f7518408000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IO.getByte(IO.java:82)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:885)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.run(Session.java:1289)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Camel (camel-101) thread #124 - sftp://testuser:******@11.11.11.11:22/download" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f748c090800 nid=0x7b46 in Object.wait() [0x00007f74cd35e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000730625758> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:327)
    - locked <0x0000000730625758> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
    - locked <0x0000000730625758> (a com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._get(ChannelSftp.java:1041)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:944)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:922)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFileToFileInLocalWorkDirectory(SftpOperations.java:675)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.retrieveFile(SftpOperations.java:542)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:317)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:155)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:142)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

During every polling, consumer first connect to server and then disconnect from the server. But during the last polling, consumer connected to SFTP server but didn't disconnect and then went idle.

**Usual log during polling :**

```
02-05-2016 20:48:36,662 INFO  (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel (camel-99) thread #117 - sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected to sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22

02-05-2016 20:48:36,662 INFO  (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer) [Camel (camel-99) thread #117 - sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected and logged in to: sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22

02-05-2016 20:48:38,539 INFO  (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel (camel-99) thread #117 - sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] JSCH -> Disconnecting from 11.11.11.11 port 22
```

**Error log after which consumer stopped polling:**

```
02-05-2016 20:59:39,392 INFO  (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations) [Camel (camel-99) thread #117 - sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected to sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22

02-05-2016 20:59:39,392 INFO  (org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer) [Camel (camel-99) thread #117 - sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22/download] Connected and logged in to: sftp://xxxx:******@11.11.11.11:22
```

Please suggest what can be done here.

Comment: When the consumers stop polling and there is something to consume, have you tried looking at the thread dump to see what the status of these threads are? I have seen this in the past, can't remember how we fixed it.. Is upgrading the camel version an option for you? It would be interesting to see if you can reproduce it using a much recent version of Camel.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have not taken any thread dump during the time. Also any idea which camel version has the fix?

Comment: I remember either we did something, or went to Camel 2.12 and it was fixed? Can you please post your entire URI for one of the polling consumers?

Comment: I have added thread dump and entire URI of polling consumer.

Comment: Can you please login to Fuse console and type "endpoint-list" and post the results?